# identifiying retired badges at foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

is it possible to identify the retired badge ?
I checked the  response for user badges but found nothing related

XXXXX1: { 
id: "XXXXX1" badgeId: "XXXXX2" name: "WSJ Urban Adventurer" description: "You really get around! The Wall Street Journal congratulates you on checking into all five boroughs of New York.

" image: { prefix: "https://playfoursquare.s3.amazonaws.com/badge/" sizes: [ 57 114 200 300 400 ] name: "/wsjadventurer.png" } unlocks: [ { checkins: [ { id: "YYY" createdAt: 123123123 type: "checkin" private: true timeZone: "America/New_York" photos: { count: 0 items: [ ] } } ] } ] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to determine if a badge has been retired via the API, but we're considering adding a relevant field to the response. Stay tuned for updates: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/changelog